# ionic project show blank page

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I work with ionic for create mobile apps so i have:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/cms/controller/mobile.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
```

mobile.php

```
{ "records":[ {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}, {"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"}, {"Name":"B's Beverages","City":"London","Country":"UK"}, {"Name":"Berglunds snabbköp","City":"Luleå","Country":"Sweden"}, {"Name":"Blauer See Delikatessen","City":"Mannheim","Country":"Germany"}, {"Name":"Blondel père et fils","City":"Strasbourg","Country":"France"}, {"Name":"Bólido Comidas preparadas","City":"Madrid","Country":"Spain"}, {"Name":"Bon app'","City":"Marseille","Country":"France"}, {"Name":"Bottom-Dollar Marketse","City":"Tsawassen","Country":"Canada"}, {"Name":"Cactus Comidas para llevar","City":"Buenos Aires","Country":"Argentina"}, {"Name":"Centro comercial Moctezuma","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, {"Name":"Chop-suey Chinese","City":"Bern","Country":"Switzerland"}, {"Name":"Comércio Mineiro","City":"São Paulo","Country":"Brazil"} ] }
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
      <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
      -->
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
          <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
          <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, when i serve my project in output i see the blank page and my code not work. what's my problem? how do fix this?

Comment: is that code complete? why no .run() method?

Comment: Can you isolate the problem? Did you console.log `$scope.names` after your response? Does it return the data but not update the view?